# Category List is not displaying in a Custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am creating a template for a custom post type called "Projects" and trying to display a list of all categories assigned to a single post.

```
<div class="blog-information left full-width">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="project-content">
                        <div class="eck-projects-single-start">
                            <a href="/project" style="text-align: left;" class="eck-projects-back-link">< Back to Projects</a>
                            <h2 class="project-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <p class="eck-projects-single-subtitle"><?php echo $fields['subtitle']; ?></p>
                            <div class="eck-projects-single-categories">
                                <?php echo get_the_category_list( ' \ ' ); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="eck-projects-single-content">
                            <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

What shows up on the single post is just an empty div; no categories are coming in from the get_the_category_list function.

I tried changing this line:
`<?php echo get_the_category_list( ' \ ' ); ?>`
to this:

```
        $args = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'ecprojects',
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'order'   => 'ASC'
                );

        $cats = get_categories($args);

        foreach($cats as $cat) {
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>">
                <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
            </a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

(ecprojects being the name of the custom post type), but got the same result.

Comment: does it work if you just use `echo get_the_category_list();`, i.e. without defining a separator?

Comment: No, I had that originally, as a matter of fact. Exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<?php the_category(' \ ') ?>` instead of `<?php echo get_the_category_list( ' \ ' ); ?>` (without `echo`...)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. It's still coming back empty.

Comment: the rest of the stuff (content, header) is echoed correctly?

Comment: Yes, everything else is coming through correctly.

Comment: "\`" is usually used to escape characters, so I would also here try to use the default `the_category();` (again, without `echo`)

Comment: Same result still...I know that I've had issues in the past with categories on Custom Post Types functioning differently than with normal post types. Is it possible this has something to do with that?

Comment: In one of my websites, I am using `the_category();` in a custom post type template and it works as expected...

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_the_terms() function for getting the terms object related to a post.
use below example for your code. here 'ecprojects' should be taxonomy name.

Note: replace get_the_ID() with post_id if you are not in loop or post template.

```
$cats = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ecprojects');

foreach($cats as $cat) {
?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>">
        <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
    </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

I hope it helps.